# Deletion of row in mysql using pdo not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
include_once "Database.php";
$server="localhost";
$db="fantasy cricket";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db=new Database($server,$db,$user,$password);

$name=$_POST["name"];
$country=$_POST["country"];
$db->removePlayerFromTeam($name,$country);
```

This is the code that I am using to delete a row ,but the deletion is not working and database remains same .The **removePlayerFromTeam($name,$country)** is given below.When i use the query "delete from demo" ,that works and all rows get deleted,but when specifying column and value its not working.
By echoing i get the desired values passed as parameter to the function.Please help me out what is going wrong.
**Thanks in advance.**

```
public function removePlayerFromTeam($n,$cn)
{
    echo "$n"."<br>"."$cn"."<br>";
    $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM demo WHERE Pname='%s' and country='%s'",$n,$cn);
    $v=$this->connection->exec($sql);
    if($v>0)echo "ok"."<br>";
    else echo "wrong"."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please change your database password immediately, you posted it to Stackoverflow and it is no longer secure.

Comment: can you print $sql which is executing....

Comment: Any error message is showing either in php end or mysql end? Please post the error message from php and mysql error log.

Comment: yes, the sql is echoed correctly

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F9C34605B8C6A3D2!12672&authkey=!ACFwpz9v9frK_ns&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG      ... neither php nor mysql is giving any error ..but no rows are getting effected for using the query and $v variable is remaining 0